# How to build accordian style debugger with DOM - a nudge?

Tags: jquery-ui, dom

I have given up doing this in pure js.  And I can't find the jquery accordian stuff i was looking over when I started this project originally.  What is the best way to do this? My code is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962243/trouble-hiding-showing-divs-in-using-dom-js-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) is **jQuery UI Accordion**.

All you need is:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Paragraph 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Paragraph 2
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to create the headinsg and sections with the variables.

Comment: @lazfish - you're not actually asking for 'how to create the headinsg and sections with the variables', are you? If you want to generate DOM in js you might want to take a look at client-side templating (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Comment: Yeah I am reading over that now. I thought this would be easy.